# Javascript get reverse any length of number in param with for loop

Tags: javascript

Here is my code snippet that's working for 4 digit of number:

```js
function rev(num) {
  num = num.toString();

  var rev = Number(num[3]) * Math.pow(10, num.length - 1);
  rev += Number(num[2]) * Math.pow(10, num.length - 2);
  rev += Number(num[1]) * Math.pow(10, num.length - 3);
  rev += Number(num[0]) * Math.pow(10, num.length - num.length);

  var div = document.createElement('div');

  div.innerHTML = rev;

  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

rev(1234);
```

I want to run a for loop to reverse any amount of number. how can I get that?
So far I've tried:

```js
function rev(num) {
  num = num.toString();

  for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    if (i < num.length + 1) {
      var rev = Number(num[i]) * Math.pow(10, num.length - i);
    } else {
      rev += Number(num[0]) * Math.pow(10, num.length - num.length);
    }
  }

  var div = document.createElement('div');

  div.innerHTML = rev;

  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

rev(1234);
```

**NB:** I only want pure JS solution, as I'm learning JS and NewBie

Comment: Why are you starting your loop at `1` instead of `0`?

Comment: `if (i < num.length + 1)` will always succeed, because the `for` loop ends when `i = num.length`.

Comment: Why not just use `Array.reverse()`?

Comment: @Barmar- let me check,

Comment: @PHPglue- Because I don't want to use any function for reversing or splice or split ...

Comment: If you do change your mind: `String(1234).split("").reverse().join("")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need the Math.pow. Why not reverse as a string as you started doing and convert at the end. And to make it easier you can start from the end:

```
function rev(num) {
  num = num.toString();
  rev = ""  
  for (var i = num.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
rev += num[i]   

  }

  var div = document.createElement('div');

  div.innerHTML = rev;

  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

rev(1234);
```

Comment: Ahh, setting `rev` to zero was great, and liked the easy answer. My answer was: http://jsfiddle.net/z03rma6f/

what an waste.... thank you so much, the shortest answer, and I was thinking something like this

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to subtract `num.length - i`. In your reversed number, the powers of 10 correspond directly to the position in the original number.

```js
function rev(num) {
  num = num.toString();
  var rev = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    rev += Number(num[i]) * Math.pow(10, i);
  }

  var div = document.createElement('div');

  div.innerHTML = rev;

  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

rev(1234);
```

Comment: Ahh, setting `rev` to zero was great, and liked the easy answer my answer was: http://jsfiddle.net/z03rma6f/

what an waste.... thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to reverse the string, relying only on `substr()`.  You could build your own `substr()`, too if need be...

```js
// reverse a string.  this could be written much tighter, but 
// here it is making the recursive idea clear
function revStr(string) {
  if (!string.length) return string;
  var l1 = string.length-1;
  var firstChars = string.substr(0,l1);
  var lastChar = string.substr(l1, 1);
  return lastChar.concat(revStr(firstChars));
}

function rev(number) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = revStr(number.toString());
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

rev(1234);
```